# Two conditionals inside an if statement (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an if statement which checks if the image is wider than 199px and if it hasn't got a < a > parent element.
**This works:**

```
    $('div.post_body').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').each(function () {
        var img = $(this);
            if (img.is('a') !== true) {
                img.wrap($('<a/>').attr('href', img.attr('src')).addClass('lightview limg'));
            }
    });
});
```

**This works**

```
    $('div.post_body').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').each(function () {
        var img = $(this);
            if (img.width() > 199) {
                img.wrap($('<a/>').attr('href', img.attr('src')).addClass('lightview limg'));
            }
    });
});
```

***This DOESN'T work:***

```
    $('div.post_body').each(function() {
    $(this).find('img').each(function () {
        var img = $(this);
            if ((img.width() > 199) && (img.is('a') !== true)) {
                img.wrap($('<a/>').attr('href', img.attr('src')).addClass('lightview limg'));
            }
    });
});
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: The image will always have a parent element; <body/> is still a parent element. Can you specify which parent element you are checking exists / doesn't exist?

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using this against?

Comment: `img` will never be `'a'` because it is an `img`.

Comment: Normally it says that you don't have any img with both conditions. You can also try just img.not('a') must be the same as your condition

Comment: `img.is('a') !== true` is an extremely convoluted way to write that condition.  How about `!img.is('a')` or `img.not('a')` or, if you insist on testing against literal boolean values, `img.is('a') === false`?

Comment: @EdS. -- `img.is('a')` will always be false because it is an `<img />` element. Therefore, it could be simplified to `( false !== true )` or `( true )`

Comment: @KevinB: I know, I saw your previous comment.  I was referring only to the expression itself, not whether or not it was correct or made any sense to begin with.

Comment: I agree with @KevinB. The second condition is meaningless. `img.is('a')` will *always* be false, because you've selected only `img` tags. So just remove it. Additionally, why are you doing two separate `each`'s here? Just do `$('div.post_body img').each()` or `$('div.post_body').find('img').each()`.

Comment: @EdS. I missed my own point after i started typing out my comment. `.not(selector)` returns an object, not a number or boolean. Therefore it will always be `true`.

Comment: @KevinB: :D  I'm not a javascript user, so I just stole that one method from your comment.  I was just struck by the unnecessarily complicated conditional.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `<a>` parent element. (It didn't show up when I submitted the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want all images directly inside the `div` that exceed a certain dimension?

```
$("div.post_body > img").wrap(function(){
    if ( $(this).width() > 199 ) {
        return $("<a>").attr("href", this.src).addClass("lightview limg");
    }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BQAZH/1/

Comment: Great! Thank you, this works. To be honest I don't know how, but it does.

Comment: @user1431427 This selects all `img` elements *immediately* within the `div.post_body`. That's what `>` does. Then the wrap method is called with an anonymous function, and this function executes once per every math (meaning once for each image). If the image width exceeds 199, we return an anchor element from the wrap function, and this anchor is then wrapped around the image currently being evaluated.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason though it works perfectly on JSFiddle, but it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't on my (test) website. Especially after refresh. Could you have a look please? http://jsfiddle.net/deswolf/SGqLg/

Comment: @ZenkTM Which image, specifically, is it not working for on your site?

Comment: Most of the time it only works on the first image (inside the .post_body divs). It should work on 1,2 and 4 (I have labelled them). Sometimes it works properly though.

Comment: @ZenkTM The script works properly; though it appears something might be preventing it from time to time.

Comment: It's strange. Thank you for your help, much appreciated. Gonna try and figure this out :S

Comment: Managed to fix it, by using: `jQuery(window).bind('load', function(){
 var $=jQuery //code });`

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the logic present in your code, you seem to be trying to test if the `img` is wrapped by an `<a></a>`, and if not, wrap it.

**If so, you can optimize your code to this:**

```
$('div.post_body img').each(function() {
  var $img = $(this);

  if (($img.width() > 199) && ($img.parent('a').length)) {
    $img
      .wrap($('<a/>').attr('href', $img.attr('src')).addClass('lightview limg'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if its parent is anchor element or not:

```
$('div.post_body img').each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
        if ((img.width() > 199) && (img.parent().get(0).tagName != 'a')) {
            img.wrap($('<a/>').attr('href', img.attr('src')).addClass('lightview limg'));
        }
});
```